# Phantomjs stops loading full page

Tags: phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS 1.9.7 under Debian to analyze page content. For some reason it stops loading page on any resource loading failure. For example, if it cannot load .js file, it finishes with status "fail". So I get

> FAIL to load the address:xxxx caused by Operation canceled

in `page.open()` status handler.

How to make PhantomJS go on loading other resources even if some of them cannot be loaded?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible that SSL is the culprit. You could try a variety of [command line options](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) to fix the loading error like:

```
--ignore-ssl-errors=true
--web-security=false
```

If you know the resource that fails to load every time, you could explicitly abort the loading by listening to the [`onResourceRequested` event](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html):

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest){
    if (requestData.url.indexOf("yourScript.js") !== -1) {
        networkRequest.abort();
    }
};
```

You could also look what kind of error this is with [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html).

Comment: Thank you for recommendation. Unfortunately I don't know the resource until it's loaded and failed.

How safe is to disable web-security option? It seems it's not the best practice and quite dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the resources that are failing by printing the error to console.

```
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
  console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};
```

And this should print something like

```
Unable to load resource (#19URL:http://www.google.com)
Error code: 5. Description: Operation canceled
```